# Добавить стили в макрос HTML

Tags: html, css, python, bootstrap

Добрый день!

Есть html документ с макросом, который выводит поля ввода:

```html
{% macro render_field(field) %}
<p>
   <b>{{ field.label }}</b><br>
 {{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}

  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li style="color:red;">{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
<p>
{% endmacro %}

<html>
  <body>
    <title>Guest Book</title>
   <form method="POST">

    {{ render_field(form.test_name) }}
    {{ render_field(form.test_email) }}
    {{ render_field(form.test_comment) }}
        {{ render_field(form.test_phone) }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send my comment</button>

        <br></br>

       <table border="1">
            <tr>
            <th width="50">Date</th>
            <th width="70">Name</th>
            <th width="50">Email</th>
            <th width="50">Phone</th>
            <th width="100">Comment</th>
            <th width="50">Actions</th>
            </tr>
           {% for record in record %}
            <tr><td>{{ record.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") }}</td><td>{{ record.name}}</td><td>{{ record.email}}</td>
        <td>{{ record.phone}}</td><td>{{ record.comment}}</td><td><a href='{{url_for('delete', record_id = record.id) }}'>Delete</a> </td></tr>{% endfor %} </table>
   </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Помогите оформить для полей ввода разные состояния. т.е. при валидном вводе информации рамка светится зеленым, при не валидном - красным

```html
<div class="form-group has-success">
   <label class="control-label" for="succ">Оформление success</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
 

 
<div class="form-group has-error">
   <label class="control-label" for="err">Оформление error</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

```
Я мог бы справится и сам, но никогда не работал с макросами.
Спасибо
```